Present Perfect + After + Past Perfect Continuous / Is this sequence correct?

Regarding the negative effects of substance abuse, as a therapist I can say that during my career I've had serious sessions with young people who have experienced extremely dangerous hallucinations after they had been drinking alcohol for more than ten days in a row.
Their experiences are explicit examples of what we should never try!

I'd like to know whether this sentence is grammatically correct and how does it sound to you.
Specifically, I'm interested in using of the past perfect continuous here.
Is this acceptable to you as a native speakers or I should use some other tense?
(N.B. I'm aware that I can use the present participle - after drinking or gerund - after their drinking, but I'd like others to explain to me whether the past perfect continuous is correct in the original sentence.)

It sounds natural to me. Why do you think it's wrong?

why not have been drinking ? The text is in present perfect  have experienced seems to relate to the present   so I think have been  drinking could work here

@PeterKirkpatrick I didn't think it's wrong, I just wasn't sure it's right. I've found some similar examples during my research in which people used the present perfect or the past perfect ("after they've/they'd drunk a huge amounts of alcohol") but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. I'm truly glad that I've found the answer! Thank you for your help!

@MickeyQ, you did at least suggest that it was wrong. Otherwise you would have no reason to twice wonder if it was correct or not. But I asked that question mainly because too often people ask if a tense is right/wrong/correct etc. The question they should really ask is, what does each tense mean? The alternatives you suggest (they've drunk or they'd drunk) are also correct, but they don't mean the same thing exactly.

#1. Have experienced hallucinations after they have been drinking... => Two tenses the same, so maybe this a single event with the hallucinations at the end (A ten day binge?) #2. Have experienced hallucinations after they had been drinking... => Had here more definitely separates the two things. The first past action is set prior to the second past action. Could be the same meaning as #1, but could also be a ten day binge followed by a hallucination some weeks later.

@PeterKirkpatrick What about "... who have experienced hallucinations after they have drunk / had drunk a huge amounts of alcohol."? Could you explain the difference between these two alternatives?

I thought that's exactly what I had explained. What don't you understand?

@PeterKirkpatrick You've explained the difference between Have experienced hallucinations after they have/had been drinking... (Present Perfect Continuous vs. Past Perfect Continuous) which I completely understand. However, the difference between the alternatives Have experienced hallucinations after they have/had drunk a huge amounts of alcohol... (Present Perfect vs. Past Perfect) you haven't explained! So, does it mean that the same logic applies here, too?

I think your question is not about different tenses but about the use of the continuous form or not. Compare these sentences. (1) They have experienced hallucinations after they had been drinking for ten days. (2) They have experienced hallucinations after they had drunk a large amount of alcohol My instinct is to use have/had been drinking in sentence #1 because it describes drinking over a period of time. In sentence #2 I would use have/had drunk because it describes the act of drinking as a single one off event. Time frame here is not important.

@PeterKirkpatrick What is the difference between these two sentences: "They have experienced hallucinations after they have drunk a large amount of alcohol." and "They have experienced hallucinations after they had drunk a large amount of alcohol."  I'm sorry but I can't see the answer to this question! Would you help me with this?

We are talking at cross purposes here. In your second post back, you asked for the difference between have/had been drinking and have/had drunk. So I thought you were asking about been drinking versus drunk. And that's what I tried to answer. The contrast between have and had is the same in either case. You asked: Does it mean the same logic applies? It looks like I should just have said Yes!
